# Slick Code Generator Not Including Schema With Table

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have two db schemas on the same server for MySQL.  I want to be able to join tables from the separate schemas (which can be done in SQL simply by specifying the schema of each table say, first_schema.some_table JOIN second_schema.another_table)

I found that this is handled easily in Slick as long as the class for the tables in question include the schema name (I added it in manually and everything worked great).  The problem is, slick's codegen isn't including the schema with it.  I'm not sure how to fix this.  I've been crawling through the source code and I'm not making much progress on the matter :(

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug in the schema reverse engineering.

Check out this guide to customizing the code generator.
http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/code-generation.html

Best would be if you determine why it happens and submit a fix to Slick if needed. This may require changed to the MySQLDriver#ModelBuilder.

To fix it just for you, you should modify the Model before giving it to the code generator. Alternatively you can override def Table#code .